# Hibernate doesn't use the name argument for @JoinTable

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I have a little problem, I have a super class defining an entity to a root table in PostgreSQL.

This class have 2 inherits table / class entity, where I want to add a `@OneToOne` join table association:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Table(name = "equipement")
public abstract class Equipement
{
   ....
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "nod")
public class Nod extends Equipement
{
    protected Cross cross;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "assoc_nod_cross", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "nod_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cross_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    public Cross getCross()
    {
        return cross;
    }

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "cross")
public class Cross extends Equipement
{
    protected Nod nod;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "assoc_nod_cross", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cross_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "nod_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    public Nod getNod()
    {
        return nod;
    }

    ...
}
```

When list all Nod or Cross entities, Hibernate want to search for the inverseJoinColumns field in the wrong table, it doesn't use the name (assoc_nod_cross), I can even put anything.

Sample :

```
Hibernate: select cross0_.id as id1_7_, cross0_.nod_id as nod_id2_1_ from cross cross0_

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column cross0_.node_id does not exist
```

Is it a problem because of the @Inheritance strategy ? Is it a bug in hibernate ? Is it a problem in my entities definition ?

Added information : I tried to switch to EclipseLink to check if it is a hibernate bug / limitation or if I am wrong somewhere. And EclipseLink works well.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a bidirectional relation between `Cross` and `Nod`? If so, you don't have to annotate both sides of the relation in this way. It is possible that this is confusing hibernate. [Here](http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/11/15/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-using-annotations/#highlighter_526106) is an example of it working. I think this should do it

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "nod")
public class Nod extends Equipement
{
    protected Cross cross;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "assoc_nod_cross", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "nod_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cross_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    public Cross getCross()
    {
        return cross;
    }

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "cross")
public class Cross extends Equipement
{
    protected Nod nod;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "cross")
    public Nod getNod()
    {
        return nod;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of a problem like that, but even without the JoinTable annotation on the Cross entity, there is the same error.

Comment: Even with `mappedBy = "cross"`?

Comment: Yes, I changed it, and keep it, as it is clearly better. But it continue to faild on me.

Comment: It seems that this strange problem is related with Hibernate. No problem with eclipselink.

Comment: Yes, I saw your edit. If it isn't too much work, you can try the same setup on entities without inheritance, just to see if it makes any difference. Btw, which hibernate version are you using?

Comment: Yes I would like to know if the inheritance is causing this problem, but as you guessed, this would be a lot of works that I can't afford to take for the moment. I will use eclipselink as it works. I was using Hibernate 4.3.6.Final.